# 4 I am trying to put array into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
zeros=np.zeros((6,6))
arra=np.array([zeros])

rownames=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
colnames=[['one','tow','three','four','five','six']]
df=pd.DataFrame(arra,index=rownames,columns=colnames)
print(df)
```

Error:
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 6, 6)

My desired output is :

```
        A  B C D E F
one     0  0 0 0 0 0
tow     0  0 0 0 0 0
three   0  0 0 0 0 0 
four    0  0 0 0 0 0
five    0  0 0 0 0 0
six     0  0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Your desired output has rows and columns swapped from your example code.  That's not the only problem but is that what you want?

Comment: `arra=np.array([zeros])` turns the 2D `zeros` array into a 3D array... you need to do `df = pd.DataFrame(zeros, index=rownames, columns=colnames)` or switch the row and column names because that won't exactly produce what you say you want....

Comment: Yes, if you use `zeros` in your `pd.DataFrame` call, this works, modulo the row/column swap.

Comment: What exactly is the point of `arra=np.array([zeros])`?

Comment: Note also that `np.zeros((6, 6))` is going to give you an array of floats, not integers.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was solved with your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((6,6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'), index=['one','tow','three','four','five','six'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize your DataFrame with a single value, you don't need to bother creating a 2D array, just pass the desired scalar to the DataFrame constructor and it will broadcast:

```
import pandas as pd

rownames=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
colnames=[['one','tow','three','four','five','six']

df=pd.DataFrame(0, index=rownames, columns=colnames)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  one tow three four five six
A   0   0     0    0    0   0
B   0   0     0    0    0   0
C   0   0     0    0    0   0
D   0   0     0    0    0   0
E   0   0     0    0    0   0
F   0   0     0    0    0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
zeros=np.zeros((6,6), dtype=int)
df=pd.DataFrame(zeros, columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F'], index=['one','tow','three','four','five','six'])
```

Understand that in your questions 'A','B','C','D','E','F' these are column names and 'one','tow','three','four','five','six' are indexes, you have confused them with rows and columns.

The reason you got that error is because of the line arra=np.array([zeros]) which converts 2d array to 1d array (like how its given below - see '[[[' which means it is 1d array of 2d array ), but you need 2d array to create a dataframe.

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: @AbdeljalilAhmed Great! Please mark this answered if it helped, thanks!